# Upload a file using PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to upload a file to a given folder.

```
<?php
$folder = "upload/";
if (is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  {   
    if (move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
         echo "File uploaded";
    } else {
         echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
    };
} else {s
     echo "File is not uploaded";
}; 
?>
```

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_POST_FILES in C:\wamp\www\sdg\import\ips.php on line 3

Comment: `$_FILES` Kindly suggest you to use google.

Comment: `$HTTP_POST_FILES` is deprecated since PHP 4.1.0

Comment: ty i replaced  
$_FILES. 
But now it says the files uploaded successfully but not file is upoaded in the folder

Comment: Have you confirmed that the browser (or whatever you are using to make the HTTP request) is actually sending the file? i.e. have you examined the HTTP request and observed the file data there? What does it look like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is one way to upload files, there are many other ways.

As @nordenheim said, `$HTTP_POST_FILES` has been deprecated since PHP 4.1.0, thus not advisable to use so.

PHP Code (upload.php)

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$allowedTypes = ['jpg', 'png'];

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // check type
    if (!in_array($imageFileType, $allowedTypes)) {
        $msg = "Type is not allowed";
    } // Check if file already exists
    elseif (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $msg = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    } // Check file size
    elseif ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        $msg = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $msg = "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
    }
}

?>
```

HTML Code to start function

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Upload File</button>
 </form>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 4.1 introduced the [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). They replace the old, long-named arrays that contain the data extracted from the request. [`$_FILES[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)  replaced[`$HTTP_POST_FILES[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), `$_GET[]` replaced `$HTTP_GET_VARS[]` and so on

For subsequent PHP 4 versions the old and the new arrays were available side by side. PHP 5 by default disabled the generation of the old arrays and introduced the [`php.ini` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) [`register_long_arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) that could be used to re-enable the creation of the old arrays.

Since PHP 5.4 the old long-named arrays were removed completely and `register_long_arrays` went together with them.

**Conclusion:** You are learning from a very old or very bad tutorial. Find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

First, write your html code like this, and don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then create a file name called upload.php

```
<?php
$path = "form/";
$target_file =  $path.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];    
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_file.$file);
if ($result) {
    echo "file successfully uploaded";
}
else {
    echo "please select your file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static function uploadFile($filepath="upload",$existCheck=0,$uniq=0){
   global $_FILES;
   try {
        // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
        // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
        if (
            !isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']) ||
            is_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'])
        ) {
            $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Invalid parameters.');return $result;
        }


        // Check $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] value.
        switch ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('No file sent.');return $result;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Exceeded filesize limit.');return $result;
            default:
                $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Unknown errors.');return $result;
        }

        // You should also check filesize here. 
        if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] > 1000000) {
            $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Exceeded filesize limit.');return $result;
        }

        // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['uploaded_file']['mime'] VALUE !!
        // Check MIME Type by yourself.
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
            $finfo->file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']),
            array(
                'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'png' => 'image/png',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
            ),
            true
        )) {
            $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Invalid file format.');return $result;
        }
        if($uniq==0){
            $temp=$filepath;
        }
        else{
            $temp=$filepath."/".uniqid()."_".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        }

        if ($existCheck==1 && file_exists($temp)) {
            $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Unknown errors.');return $result;
        }
        if(@copy($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $temp)) {
            return $result["status"]="success";
        } 
        $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]=('Unknown errors.');return $result;

    } catch (Exception $e) {

            $result["status"]="fail";$result["errors"]= $e->getMessage();return $result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
    $fileType = $_FILES['profileimage']['type'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['profileimage']['name'];

    $array = explode(".", $fileName);
    $ext  = $array[count($array)-1];

     $imageAutoName = "profileimagehr".$rsinssupp.".".$ext;


    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tmp_name'],'img/user/'.$imageAutoName))     
    {
      $msg = "";
    }
    else
    {
      $iquery = "UPDATE tblname SET  filane = '".$imageAutoName."' WHERE id = ".$rsinssupp."";
      $obj->edit($iquery);
    }
```

Comment: Please note that "code only answers" are discouraged. This isn't really helpful for future readers. Please explain your answer!

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);     
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

create one images folder in your project folder and run this file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use [phpUpload](https://github.com/fabriziomanca/phpUpload) class

```
$pUp = new phpUpload($_FILES['file']);

//$pUp->maxSize('1024');

//$pUp->allowedType(["image/jpeg", "image/png"]);

//$pUp->newName("New_name");

$pUp->run('destination/folder'); // Move the file to a specific folder
```