# Convert POSTed Image to Base64

Tags: php, forms, file, post, base64

I have a site that I am working on and it uses the imgur api to upload user's profile picture, but it needs to be base64 to use the function I have:

```
function imgur($image) {
    $client_id = "client_id_some_numbers_and_stuff";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image)));
    $reply = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $reply = json_decode($reply);
    $link = $reply->data->link;
    return $link;
}
```

I get the image from a form input (`<input type="file" id="pp" name="pp">`). When I get the data from `$_POST["pp"]`, it is set to the string of the filename, and nothing useful.

How can I get the image file and either pass it into the `imgur()` function, or convert it into base64 and then pass that into the `imgur()` function, and just remove the base64 encoding from the function.

Thanks :)

Edit: This post is different that the one marked as duplicate becuase I want to know how to send the form data elsewhere, and not have it uploaded to my site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)

Comment: @Lashane I'm not trying to upload it, I'm trying to get the base64 data from a post form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

info of upload file contains $_FILES array

you need to get your upload file path in server and translate it into base64

```
$image = $_FILES["pp"]["tmp_name"];
$type = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($image);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
imgur($base64);
```

Comment: I'll try that out as soon as I can, but I tried a var_dump of $_FILES and it was an empty array

Comment: @RedXTech your html form have right enctype? Is it enctype='multipart/form-data' ? Do you use ajax? Post the code of your form

Comment: Gimme a few minutes, and I'll put it up as soon as I can access it.

Comment: Had to change some things up a bit - just called `imgur()` on the `$data` variable and that worked fine. Thanks! (also I initially forgot to change the enctype so that was a problem)