# Uploading file from form with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

So, I used a form to upload files to a directory.
The PHP code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cvfile1']['tmp_name'], '/uploads/'.$oor1 . '_CV_' . $firstname . '_' . $lastname);
}
```

But when I execute it, it seems to not place the file anywhere. I have been refreshing the uploads directory for a while, hoping it would show up.

The variables have been declared and pulled off from the form

Comment: $_FILES['cvfile1']['name'] should be $_FILES['cvfile1']['tmp_name'], btw what error are you getting..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php check

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple file upload

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

OR

`<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />`