# Php file won't upload error 6 (Missing a temporary folder)

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

I have a PHP website and I am trying to create a page where people can upload an image to the server.

However it is not working and I am getting an error code 6 from the files variable.

I have researched this and apparently it means that it is missing a temporary directory, however I have correctly set the temporary folder in the php.ini and it still won't work.

Here is the contents of the $_FILES array:

```
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => maxresdefault.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 6 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Edit: I am running IIS on windows 10 as my server

Edit: Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sys_vars["uploads"]++;

$target_dir = "../";
$target_file = $target_dir . $sys_vars["uploads"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"];
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 0;
        //header("Location: upload.php?error=File is not an image.");
        echo "File is not an image.";
        die();
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    //header("Location: upload.php?error=Sorry, your file is too large.");
    die();
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.";
    echo $imageFileType;
    echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $uploadOk = 0;
    //header("Location: upload.php?error=Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.");
    die();
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
    //header("Location: upload.php");
    die();

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "/")) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        print_r ($_FILES);
        //header("Location: upload.php?error=Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share your code for upload the image to review what is wrong?

Comment: Something with permissions to that folder Maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)