# upload an image with a comments form

Tags: php, sql, forms, file-upload

I have got a comments area on my website. It displays a default image and then a persons comment. I would like to set up the form so that when a person sends a comment they have the option to upload a small image of themselves to the images folder. When the form sends I would like the image_path record to populate where the image is within the images folder. ie images/myphoto.jpg
HERE IS THE FORM

```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comment-form" action="form-post.php">
    <table class="submit-table">
    <tr>
            <td><p>First Name:</p></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="First" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Last Name</p></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Last" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td><p>Your Comment: </p></td>
            <td><textarea name="Comment" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="file" name="image_path" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png" />
        <p>Feel free to upload a small photo of yourself (Optional)</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/></td>  <td>All Comments are moderated and will be posted once approved.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

HERE is the FORM HANDLER

```
 <?php

//$sql = "SELECT ID, firstname, Comment, Image_path FROM comment";
//   
//$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$firstname = $_POST["First"];
$lastname = $_POST["Last"];
$comment = $_POST["Comment"];
$imagepath = $_POST["image_path"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (Comment, firstname, lastname, Image_path, Approved)
VALUES ('$comment', '$firstname','$lastname','$imagepath','2')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "<h4>Thankyou - We have received your comment.</h4>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image_path"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if ($target_file == "upload/") {
        $msg = "cannot be empty";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check if file already exists
    else if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $msg = "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check file size
    else if ($_FILES["image_path"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        $msg = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    else if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $msg = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_path"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $msg = "The file " . basename($_FILES["image_path"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

I have got the information uploading to the database and image uploading to the images folder but the file is not being linked to the image path. Can someone please tell me how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: Add in your form attribute with that value -  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: On how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php

Comment: Thank you for the link. I understand that will, in itself, upload the file but it will not place the path in the image_path database column for each record being submitted. The attribute I will definitely add in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question, It was actually quite simple. I used the target file variable and placed it as a value for the image path

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$firstname = $_POST["First"];
$lastname = $_POST["Last"];
$comment = $_POST["Comment"];
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image_path"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1; 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (Comment, firstname, lastname, Image_path, Approved)
VALUES ('$comment', '$firstname','$lastname','$target_file','2')";  

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "<h4>Thankyou - We have received your comment.</h4>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image_path"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if ($target_file == "upload/") {
        $msg = "cannot be empty";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check if file already exists
    else if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $msg = "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check file size
    else if ($_FILES["image_path"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        $msg = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    else if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $msg = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_path"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $msg = "The file " . basename($_FILES["image_path"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```