# Wordpress export csv to local /wp-content/uploads

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put csv file under /wp-content/uploads instead of downloading it . Following  php code download this csv file

I am using this php code

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$stream = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
fputcsv($stream, $csv_header);
foreach($arrCSV as $key => $assoc_row){
    $numeric_row = array();
    foreach ($csv_header as $header_name) {
        mb_convert_variables('UTF-8', $assoc_row[$header_name]);
        $numeric_row[] = $assoc_row[$header_name];
    }
    fputcsv($stream, $numeric_row);
```

Comment: What's your question? Note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service, so it's unlikely somebody will provide a code for you without showing any attempt to solve it

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$stream = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
fputcsv($stream, $csv_header);` This code is use for download csv file I want to change it to upload csv file to specific path directory. which function use instead of `fputcsv` Thank you

Comment: You may check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php or any of the many tutorials online on how to upload files using php. It's different from specifying a few headers and forcing a file download and can't be achieved by just changing a few lines in your provided code.