# How to send file to $_FILE through html form?

Tags: php, html, web, web-development-server

Well pretty simple question.. But can't get it right for some reason.

What would be the html code to send a file to this?

`move_uploaded_file($FILES["upload"]["tmpname"], $_POST["name"]);`

Here's mine but when I used it and echo/vardump everything, I only have 'name' and not the file

```
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Upload File</button>

 </form>
```

Thank you

Comment: check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)

Comment: I have tried using "upload" has the ID in the form also but that doesn't help. $_FILE is always empty

Comment: Is that an exact copy/paste of your HTML?  Because this `<input type="name" name"tmp"/>` doesn't match up with this `$_POST["name"]`.  Also, can you put your actual PHP code in your question and not just one line of it out of context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

i try to add a comment  but i can't

first check if upload permission  is on in php.ini

```
file_uploads = On
```

If it set to on check your upload directory which you added in uploader.php file and use if to check $_FILES['upload'] is empty
this is a simple code to uploader.php file

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_FILES['upload'])) 
    {
        $path = "upload/"; /// directory to upload 
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']).
                " has been uploaded";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }else {
    echo 'No file selected to upload ';
}
```