# Placing Image into WordPress Custom Post Type's (Not ACF) Custom Meta Field using wp_handle_upload() and add_post_meta()

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, plugins, metadata

I have wrote a very basic plug-in for use on WordPress, it creates a Custom Post Type (CPT) that has multiple custom meta fields.

I cannot seem to echo out the Image URL. I have tried a heck of a lot of other similar posts solutions but they all seem to relate in some way back to Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plug-in which I am not using.

This is the form code, capturing the data and attempting to put it into the CPT:

```
<?php
// Handle Form Submissions
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['post-type']) &&  $_POST['post-type'] == "testimonial") :
    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['your-profile-picture'])) {
        if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        }

        $uploaded_profile_picture = $_FILES['your-profile-picture'];

        $upload_overrides = array(
            'test_form' => false
        );

        $move_profile_picture = wp_handle_upload($uploaded_profile_picture, $upload_overrides);

        if ( $move_profile_picture && ! isset( $move_profile_picture['error'] ) ) {
            echo __('File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.', 'testmionial') . "\n";
            var_dump($move_profile_picture);
            $your_profile_picture = $move_profile_picture;
        } else {
            echo $move_profile_picture['error'];
        }
    } else { 
        echo 'Please provide a profile picture.';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['your-name'])) {
        $post_title = $_POST['your-name'] . '\'s Testimonial';
        $your_name = $_POST['your-name'];
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['your-role'])) {
        $your_role = $_POST['your-role'];
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter your role at this company.';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['your-company'])) {
        $your_company = $_POST['your-company'];
    } else { 
        echo 'Please enter your company name.';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['your-testimonial'])) {
        $your_testimonial = $_POST['your-testimonial'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter your testimonial URL.';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['your-background-image'])) {
        if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        }

        $uploaded_profile_picture = $_FILES['your-background-image'];

        $upload_overrides = array(
            'test_form' => false
        );

        $move_background_image = wp_handle_upload($uploaded_profile_picture, $upload_overrides);

        if ( $move_background_image && ! isset( $move_background_image['error'] ) ) {
            echo __('File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.', 'testimonial') . "\n";
            var_dump($move_background_image);
            $your_background_image = $move_background_image;
        } else {
            echo $move_background_image['error'];
        }
    } else { 
        echo 'Please provide a background image.';
    }

    /*if (isset ($_POST['your-profile-picture'])) {
        $your_profile_picture = $_POST['your-profile-picture'];
    } else { 
        echo 'Please provide a profile picture.';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['your-background-image'])) {
        $your_background_image = $_POST['your-background-image'];
    } else { 
        echo 'Please select a background image.';
    }*/


    if (isset($_POST['post-type'])) {
        $post_type = $_POST['post-type'];
    } else {
        echo 'Unable to get post type.';
    }

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $testimonial_args = array(
        'post_title'                => $post_title,

        'your_profile_picture'      => $your_profile_picture,
        'your_name'                 => $your_name,
        'your_role'                 => $your_role,
        'your_company'              => $your_company,
        'your_testimonial'          => $your_testimonial,
        'your_background_image'     => $your_background_image,

        'post_type'                 => $post_type,
        'post_status'               => 'publish'
    );

    //save the new post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($testimonial_args, true);

    $your_profile_picture           = $your_profile_picture;
    $your_name                      = $_POST['your-name'];
    $your_role                      = $_POST['your-role'];
    $your_company                   = $_POST['your-company'];
    $your_testimonial               = $_POST['your-testimonial'];
    $your_background_image          = $your_background_image;

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_profile_picture',     $your_profile_picture, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_name',                $your_name, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_role',                $your_role, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_company',             $your_company, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_testimonial',         $your_testimonial, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'your_background_image',    $your_background_image, true);

    if ($post_id != '') : ?>
        <script>
            alert('Testimonial details successfully submitted!');
        </script>
    <?php else : ?>
        <script>
            alert('Testimonial details submission was unsuccessful!');
        </script>
    <?php endif;
endif; ?>

<div class="testimonial-form">
    <div class="testimonial-form-inner">
        <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-profile-picture">Your Profile Picture (145px x 145px)</label>
                <input type="file" id="your-profile-picture" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" tabindex="1" name="your-profile-picture" onchange="validateImageFileType()" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-name">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="your-name" value="" tabindex="1" size="50" name="your-name" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-role">Your Role</label>
                <input type="text" id="your-role" value="" tabindex="3" size="50" name="your-role" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-company">Your Company</label>
                <input type="text" id="your-company" value="" tabindex="4" size="50" name="your-company" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-testimonial">Your Testimonial</label>
                <textarea id="your-testimonial" name="your-testimonial" tabindex="5" rows="5" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="your-background-image">Your Background Image (900px x 492px)</label>
                <input type="file" id="your-background-image" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" tabindex="1" name="your-background-image" onchange="validateImageFileType()" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="9" name="submit"/>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="post-type" value="testimonial" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post-type' ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the output of the data, which loops through a query echoing out the requested fields for each post, however leaves the background images blank or null:

```
<?php
// Loop through CPT Testimonial and add to slider
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($loop != '') : ?>

    <div class="testimonials">

        Testimonials V1

        <div id="testimonial-slider" class="testimonial-slider"> 

            <?php
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                $background_image_id    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_background_image_id', true);
                $background_image       = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $background_image_id, 'full' );
                $profile_image_id       = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_profile_picture_id', true);
                $profile_image          = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $profile_image_id, 'full' );
                var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID()));
                die(); ?>

                <div class="testimonial-slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $background_image; ?>);">

                    <div class="testimonial-profile-picture" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $profile_image; ?>);"></div>

                    <div class="testimonial-content">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_testimonial', true); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="testimonial-signature">
                        <div class="testimonial-name"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_name', true); ?></div>
                        <div class="testimonial-role"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_role', true); ?></div>
                        <div class="testimonial-company"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_company', true); ?></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php 
            endwhile; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

As requested in the comments, the var dump of the post is as follows:

```
array(6) {
    ["your_profile_picture"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        NULL
    }
    ["your_name"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(12) "Jason"
    }
    ["your_role"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(13) "Web Developer"
    }
    ["your_company"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(6) "Example"
    }
    ["your_testimonial"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        string(231) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
    }
    ["your_background_image"]=&gt;
    array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        NULL
    }
}
```

Lastly when submitting a complete form, with all the expected data present, the response from the simple validation is:

```
Please provide a profile picture.Please select a background image.

Notice: Undefined variable: your_profile_picture in /var/sites/d/doopsdesigns.co.uk/public_html/test/clicky/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-lister/templates/testimonial-submission-form.php on line 95

Notice: Undefined variable: your_background_image in /var/sites/d/doopsdesigns.co.uk/public_html/test/clicky/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-lister/templates/testimonial-submission-form.php on line 100

Notice: Undefined index: your-profile-picture in /var/sites/d/doopsdesigns.co.uk/public_html/test/clicky/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-lister/templates/testimonial-submission-form.php on line 109

Notice: Undefined index: your-background-image in /var/sites/d/doopsdesigns.co.uk/public_html/test/clicky/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-lister/templates/testimonial-submission-form.php on line 114
```

Please can we look to find a solution that will echo out the url of the image into the background-image styles?

Regarding the possible duplicate, the part I am struggling with is the passing of the file to the database, I have updated my question to my latest code that is attempting similar methods to the referred post but there is no explanation as to how I pass the uploaded image to the data being inserted into the database.

There is also no reference to using wp_handle_upload which would be my preferred method :)

Comment: Are you using the ACF plugin or not? At least in your code you're not using ACF's functions anywhere. ACF already provides forms functionality for editing custom fields (including images). If you want to implement all this without ACF, you cannot just put "meta fields" right into the `wp_insert_post()` arguments.. those will be ignored. You'll have to use the `'meta_input' => array(array('key' => 'foo', 'value' => 'bar')),` structure for this.

Comment: I am not using ACF. I have made the fields myself and populated them with the second block of code in my question.

Comment: Its difficult for us to say without seeing this in action. Have you confirmed that the image id is being saved successfully into the database? Add this  `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID()); die()l` inside your while loop where you are outputting the images, this will show you all the meta data including the background image info - check that `your_background_image_id` has the correct value and edit your question to paste in the relevant parts from the var_dump so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: I am going to quickly rebuild my question with hopefully more complete code. As I am going to submit the form it is now telling me I need to provide images. I also have the output you requested.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - just dropping a notification to say I have updated my question. Thanks for the guidance in getting my question easier to answer.

Comment: It looks like you are not getting the uploaded image in the first place, so it is not getting saved to the database so there is nothing to show. You can't simply use `$_POST['input-field-name']` to get a file, there is more too it. There is an answer about how to do this on Stack Overflow already, so I'll direct you to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I will go check it out for sure. Have you noticed the commented out code within the form code, this is what I was trying to achieve here, but I hit yet another road block. What do you think of that commented out code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220520/discussion-between-jason-is-my-name-and-fluffykitten).